# validate username unique getting error

Tags: java, android, boolean

I want to verify the username already exist or not, so the code shown as below, i put this code in **protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){//put this code inside here, am I correct?}**

```
public boolean verification(String _username) {
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + "LOGIN" + " WHERE " + "USERNAME" + " = ?", new String[] {_username});
        boolean exists = c.moveToFirst();
        c.close();
        return exists;
    }
```

and I want to check this when user click the **register button**, so put the code as shown below in **public void onClick(View v) {//put this code inside here, am I correct?}**

```
// check if user is exists?         
            if(verification(userName) == true){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Username already exists", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
                }
```

when i run the application click the **register button**, the apps was force to close.
I get the logcat as shown:
[image: logcat errors]

any idea?
or how to make sure the username are unique? sorry I'm still a newbie.

**EDIT**
Problem solved when my code as below:

```
if(loginDataBaseAdapter.verification(userName) == false){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Username already exists", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
                }
```

but it can't verify user neither I put true or false, any idea?

Comment: have you initialized db?

Comment: yes..
public  SQLiteDatabase db;

Comment: SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();. something like this for initialization

Comment: @user2301281 you wrote about declaration not initialization... where is it?

Comment: i have this statement in another class, am I need to rewrite in this class?

'    public  LoginDataBaseAdapter open() throws SQLException 
  {
   db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
   return this;
  }
    '

Comment: thanks, if i change the statement become "if(loginDataBaseAdapter.verification(userName) == false){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Username already exists", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return;
    }"
but the problem now is it can't verify the username already exist or not. why?
@Raghunandan

Comment: if i put loginDataBaseAdapter.verification(userName) == true, then everytime i click register button it will show "Username already exists" what is the problem? 
@StinePike

Answer (score 3):

This is a NPE case, causing by line 87. As you have mentioned above your line 87 is

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + "LOGIN" + " WHERE " + "USERNAME" + " = ?", new String[] {_username});
```

So this exception is occurring because you are trying to operate on a reference that is `null`. and here that variable is `db`.

You should put a null check before performing a query:

```
if(null == db){
// Initialize your db
}
```

Also, following link may help you to know about database in android
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Comment: thanks, but after i initialize  SQLiteDatabase, everything go smooth, the problem now is I can't verify the username neither true or false.

Comment: That is why there is a null check, if in case you lose the connection. This check gives you a second chance to reinitialize the connection. And if app is working fine does not ensure that things are going right, because may be connection was not established ever and since you did not perform action on connection so stuff was behaving correctly.

Answer (score 2):

There is a NullPointerException in line 87 of SignUPActivity. That's the reason for the crash. You should check what is in this line.

Comment: in line 87 is 
  Cursor c = db.rawQuery( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + "LOGIN" + " WHERE " + "USERNAME" + " = ?", new String[] {_username});
but I don't know what is the error, my table name is LOGIN